# How to sort a varchar numerically using the api

Tags: api

I'm trying to find the activity_type with the highest value, so I can ++ that value and insert a new activity type. I thought this would be easy.

I cannot sort on the "value" column of the `option_value` table because it is a varchar column containing (in this case) numbers.  Take the following api call:

```
civicrm_api3('OptionValue', 'getsingle', [
  'option_group_id' => 'activity_type',
  'options' => ['sort' => 'value DESC', 'limit' => 1]
]);
```

This ought to return the activity type with the highest value. However, it returns "9" because I guess mysql thinks the string "9" > "62" (which is the actual max in my sandbox).

Anyone have a good approach to suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I see if we try to modify the sort col with any sql defined functions, it gets returned with the Error Message. For Eg - `['sort' => 'CAST(value AS decimal) DESC']` returns

> Unknown field specified for sort. Cannot order by 'CAST(value AS decimal) DESC'.

Maybe, there should be some modification in [`CRM_Utils_Rule::mysqlOrderBy()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Rule.php#L129-L146) to either handle such cases.

Or we can simply use `get` instead of `getsingle` and then order the returned result values using array functions.